# Сократить условие

Tags: php

Есть функция class'a:

```
 public function blockList() {
  global $db, $avatar_path;

  $template = '';

  $q = $db->query("SELECT `vk_id`, `avatar_id` FROM `users` LIMIT 28");

  $i = 1;

  while($d = $db->assoc($q)) {
   $vk_id = $d['vk_id'];
   $avatar_id = $d['avatar_id'];

   $template .= '
         <div class="user'.(($i == 1 || $i == 5 || $i == 9) ? '' : ' left').'">
          <img src="'.$avatar_path.'/'.$avatar_id.'.png" title="'.($i + 4).'">
         </div>
   ';

   $i++;
  }

  return $template;
 }
```

Каким образом избавиться от `$i == 1 || $i == 5 || $i == 9`? Постоянно прописывать так числа не вариант.

Comment: @ModaL, (in_array($i, Array(1, 5, 9))?'':'left') можно попробовать так, если я вас правильно понял)

Comment: @Jeix, нет, я имею ввиду, чтобы оно как-то само определяло эти числа: 1,5,9

Comment: @ModaL, а откуда оно их берет? И у класса определяются методы, не функции (хоть в underlying code они зачастую ничем и не отличаются)

Comment: `$i = 0;`
`$i % 4 == 0` - как раз и будет 1ый, 5ый, 9ый, 13ый, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если посчитать, что ряд 1, 5, 9 это 4*k+1, то общие у них последние два бита: всегда `01`. Можно проверять как-то так:

```
if( $i & 0b11 ^ 0b01) { // это НЕ 1,5,9 и далее 
} else { // это 1 или 5 или 9 ..
}
```

Слева направо: оставляем только два младших бита; xor'им с 01. В итоге 0 (false) будет только если число оканчивается на `01`, в остальных случаях трансформируется в true.

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/Kni3pb)

Comment: Вот это как раз и называют "Индусский код".

Comment: @Равнодушный, индусский код - это код, которому место на [одном сайте](http://govnokod.ru).  
Тут же забавный хак, который требует хороших знаний в теме хранении данных в двоичном виде, который работает :)

Comment: @TheDoctor, "Индусский код" - это метод решения задачи не очевидным и нечитабельным методом. Как-то совсем уж специфично решать классическую задачу на остаток от деления через побитовые операторы.

Comment: @Равнодушный, как по мне - так это определение хака, написанный хакером.  
Решение задачи нестандартно - это круто, а не специфично.  
Идусский код - криво написанный, но каким-то чудом работающий код ([лурк](https://lurkmore.to/Индусский_код)). Тут всё понятно, лаконично и красиво.  
Думаю @Sergiks просто с асма или подобного языка.

Comment: @Равнодушный да, я выпендрился, ну и что? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Про остаток (пусть и неправильный – ОП хочет 1,5,9, а не 0,4,8) написали вы, я предложил другой способ. Да здравствует разнообразие решений.

Comment: @Sergiks, лично я задолбался поддерживать 150+ типовых скриптов с "разнообразием решений". Но даже этот факт не отменяет неочевидность Вашего решения. Если математические знания автора вопроса не помогли ему придти к моему варианту решения, то применив Ваш вариант он запутается еще больше. А стерев комментарии, запутает всех, кому придется поддерживать код.

Comment: @Равнодушный, никто не против Ваших действительно весомых доводов, я бы такое тоже в код не включил (хотя кого я обманываю? Включил бы - комментирую я обильно), но говорить что код плохой только из-за неочевидности - глупо и неправильно.

Comment: @Равнодушный напомню, что Хэшкод – не место, где за автора пишут код, который ещё и легко поддерживать равнодушным. Тут помогают, будят интерес и расширяют познания.